# How can i edit default Magento 2 New Products widget template?

Tags: magento2

I want to edit **default Magento 2 New Products Grid widget content**:

The file located here:

> **vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/new/content**

But when I'm done with editing its going removed on every update.

So how can I edit on my own temlpate?

Answer (score 0):

copy these files ( or what ever template you want to change ) to your theme directory and change it. the file location would be :

```
Your-Package/Your-theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/widget/
```

**Remember :**

you can override any template by copying that file to your theme package. However, you need to take care some naming convention and path of files i.e

1 - if there is vendor module naming "`module-catalog`" it will become `Magento_Catalog` in your theme folder and if there is module in vendor "`module-grouped-product`" it will become `Magento_GroupedProduct` ( - will be removed and first letter will be become upper case )

2 - All your templates will be placed in **templates** folder and **layout** folders like ( Magento_Catalog/tempates , Magento_Catalog/layout ) there will not be any view and frontend folders.

Comment: I have done it and changed the code to {{widget type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget" display_type="all_products" show_pager="0" products_count="4" template="Xx/xx/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}} but it's not working.

Comment: it will not work like that, you also need to compile and deploy static content again

Comment: Also, you would need to make some changes in widget.xml to to effect your changes, did you check this post ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162950/magento-2-change-on-widget-template-not-applied-to-frontend